# How to get a drop-down menu to overlay other elements

Tags: html, css, menu, position, overlay

I am creating a little website and I can't get the drop-down menu, which comes out of the "gallery" button when I hover on it, to overlay the paragraph below the menu instead of pushing the whole content down. I've already tried every combination of `position: relative; z-index: 9999;`. However, when I set `position: absolute;` for the `<ul>` element it actually works, but messes up all the layout of `<ul>` items. Please help me to get this done because I'm starting to bump my head... [Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/mtwpb5fx/). You can see how the paragraph goes down when you hover on the "gallery" button. I wish the paragaph stayed where it is and the drop-down menu overlayed it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First position the parent element as `relative` to make it [establish a new containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) for absolutely positioned descendants:

```css
.menu-item {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* <-- added declaration */
}
```

Then, position the nested `<ul>` absolutely, add `top`, `left` offsets as well as `width`:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mtwpb5fx/2/)**

```css
.menu-item ul {
    margin-top: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: absolute;  /* <-- added declarations */
    left: 0; top: 100%;  /*     here               */
    width: 100%;         /*     and here...        */

    transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Well that's a piece of a miracle! You saved hours of my time! Thank you! All that I needed was that `left: 0; top: 100%; width: 100%;` properties! Thank you again!!!

Comment: Could you please also tell me why the `top: 100%` property makes the `<ul>` nicely layout under the `<a>` element? From the first thought it seems that it should make the `<ul>` to appear right near the top edge of it's container, but thankfully it's not the case, because I need it just right under the `<a>` element.

Comment: @Salivan Of course. for absolutely positioned elements — whose their position value is `absolute` or `fixed` — [`top` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) specifies the distance between top margin of the element and top margin of the element's containing block. Also a percentage value on `top` is relative to the `height` of the containing block. Therefore by setting `top` to `100%` we can make sure that the element will be positioned under the containing block.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, by setting the `top` property to 100% we force the gap between the element and its container to be as big as possible, because 100% means the gap should be the full height of the container. Right?

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate people that don't refuse to pay a couple of seconds of their time for others.

Comment: @Salivan Don't mention it. I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your .menu-item a relative position

```
position: relative;
```

and now you can set your `ul` to `absolute` position without messing up your layout.

Here's an updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtwpb5fx/1/)

Comment: But I can clearly see a messed up layout. Are you sure about your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, the layout is still the same except for the `ul`. You need to style it.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the layout of `<ul>` messes up after setting the `position: absolute;` property. @Hashem Qolami just gave me what I really needed. Sorry, but his example was a little bit better but thank you too!

Comment: Yeah, and that was what did the whole trick. I would have been trying to style it for ages, because this is my second day working with CSS, but he just showed me the simplest and clearest way.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work on frame builds..

Example: you have two frames top with content in them and you have got a CSS dropdown menu on the top frame. When you come on the menu, the sub menu is not seen in front of the content page.