# CSS positioning relative to an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML5 page, which has a `<header>` element containing the `<nav>` section.

Due to the style and design of the overall header, the nav is **absolutely** positioned within the header, which is itself  **relative**ly positioned.

This works perfectly for anchors `<a>` for which it was originally intended. However, I now have need to add a drop-down menu and am using this one:

http://webdesignerhut.com/css-dropdown-menu/
and
[How to get a drop-down menu to overlay other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732488/how-to-get-a-drop-down-menu-to-overlay-other-elements)

But the issue with this and any other CSS dropdown menus that I have found is that they require the parent element to be ***relatively*** positioned, but I can't mark the parent `<nav>` as being both relative *and* absolute. I am also finding similar CSS requirements with my investigation of `jQuery` alternatives.

Markup:

```
<html>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>menu option</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>menu option</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>submenu option</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    ...
  </main>
</html>
```

CSS (simplified, this works for non-dropdown selection)

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
}
```

CSS (required by dropdowns)

```
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

So how can I make the `nav` element act as a `position:relative` to its children but act as a `position:absolute` to its parent?

### EDIT

Here is a fiddle trying to outline what's going on. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8j9z8wak/

It seems the original cause is that the `header` element (of which `nav` is a child) has `overflow:hidden` which helps with resizing on mobile devices and variable screen sizes with floating images on the top left corner of the header image.

I currently on the fiddle have tried to play with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` but this results in scrollbars and not the intended overflow that works with removing `overflow:hidden`

re  (just for your info.) : There are a lot of CSS / HTML parts to the fiddle, the issue is not the bare bones of the navigation but the way it fits with these other parts, so I've kept them in.

I have the `nav` as a child of `header` and I need the header to use `overflow:hidden`, but `nav` CSS menu works as intended without `overflow:hidden`.

- I have retained media queries as the `overflow:hidden` is required for smaller screen size handling.
- The navigation menu elements have a floating pair of parts that centre the float as found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508512/3536236 . This was applied just for today because all dropdown menu systems use floating elements, and they need to be centred.

Comment: It sounds like you should have another container element around `<nav>`, have that positioned absolute and nav as relative.

Comment: I have an issue using the two div method that the dropdown does not display, it is hidden behind the `main` element.

Comment: Does it hide behind main or is it not visible outside the nav or header element? If nav or header has overflow:hidden; it may just not be overflowing. Otherwise you might want to add some z-index's to force it infront.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? That's an easy question, but without a test case it's hard to view what is your requirement.

Comment: @DarrenGourley I have used `z-index` but that hasn't helped. I'm now trying with removing overflow hidden...

Comment: ok so @DarrenGourley removing overflow hidden from the `header` element does work, it makes it work but that causes secondary effects associated with the `header` element, however setting an overflow for the `nav` element doesn't overwrite the `header` elements overflow setting. Which is so close yet not quite a success. Any ideas?

Comment: @Martin I assume you're using overflow hidden because elements within it are floated? You could try removing the floats from the elements and rework that, otherwise you could give your header a height.

Comment: @DarrenGourley removing overflow hidden causes , er, overflow on resize or on mobile sizing of the page. I need the `header` element specifically to retain overflow hidden but the `nav` element and its children to pop-out of that . Arr so close!

Comment: @DarrenGourley I have tried using `overflow-x / y` to define each one but that makes the header act like a frame. I am making a fiddle now....

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have added a fiddle and small update

Answer (score 0):

Add another container element inside the `<nav>` and then use `position: relative` on the inner container:

```
<html>
  <header>
    <nav>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>menu option</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>menu option</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>submenu option</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    ...
  </main>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
}

nav div {
  position: relative;
}

nav div ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, I have run this through and have a possibly related issue that the dropdown part of the menu does not display and appears to be "behind" the `<main>` part of the page structure. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Check this code to clear the concept.

```css
div{
    border:1px solid #f00;    
}
.gp{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.p{
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:5%;
    z-index:1;
    width:90%;
    height:50px;
}
.c{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gp">
    Grand Parents
    <div class="p">
        Parents
        <div class="c"> childs </div>
    </div>
</div>
```