# How to show html table always on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating table

```css
#myUL li a {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" list="myUL" onclick="openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" style="width:90%; ">
<ul id="myUL" hidden=true>
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On click of input tag is `myUL` is opening. Now I implemented this on the top of some box. Now the problem is when I am clicking, `myUL` is not displaying fully because it is getting hide because of box. How Can show this always on top.

Note :

- Applying z-index is also not working.
- Typing in input is also not working.

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Comment: try to make a fiddle and share.

Comment: @David where is your `openingList()` ?

Comment: check the CSS structure of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732488/how-to-get-a-drop-down-menu-to-overlay-other-elements

Answer (score 1):

You should use `z-index`,however, it works with (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`) 
 So You have to add Position attribute to your `#myUL li a` style

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#myUL li a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: How can you describe it?